# For my project in Launchpad, how do I send all merge requests to a mailing list?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

I have a project in Launchpad with a bzr tree. I want all merge requests against that tree to have notifications set to my developer mailing list. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The mailing list must be associated with a LP user or team. For teams, it is under "Set Contact Information".
2. Set this LP user or team as the "Reviewer" of the bzr tree, under "Set branch reviewer"
3. On the mailing list, allow implicit inbound emails from LP. For example, with Mailman, under "Privacy Options, Recipient Filters", set "Alias names  (regexps) which qualify as explicit to or cc destination names for this list." to: `mp\+.*@code\.launchpad\.net`

Now all merge request emails will be delivered to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Register the mailing list as the owner of the branch?

Comment: This doesn't seem sufficient. However, I think I've found the right process for this.